# compilation problem while trying to iterate a class of ArrayList<Obj>

Tags: java, oop

> I have a class to generate an Arraylist it all seems to work but in main it produces a compilation problem which I guess does not recognize my variable name as an ArrayList

```
public class Order {
//Attributes
private ArrayList<DessertItem> order;

//Constructors 
Order(){
    order = new ArrayList<DessertItem>();
}   

//Methods
public ArrayList<DessertItem> getOrderList(){
    return order;
}//end of getOrderList

public void add(DessertItem aItem) {
    order.add(aItem);
}//end of add

public int itemCount() {
    return order.size();
}//end of itemCount
}//end of class


public class DessertShop {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create order
Order order = new Order();

//create obj and adding to the order
Candy c1 = new Candy("Candy Corn", 1.5, .25);
order.add(c1);

for (DessertItem item : order) {//here is where is marked the error
System.out.printf("%s.%n", item.getName());
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For future reference, it would help if you were to include a copy of the compiler error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is hard to read.  I'd recommend paying attention to formatting.

`order` is an `Order`, not an `ArrayList`.  It has an `ArrayList`.  That's what you want to iterate over.

Try this:

```
for (DessertItem item : order.getOrderList()) {
    System.out.printf("%s.%n", item.getName());
}
```

A lot of your comments are clutter.  I'd remove them.

I'd prefer a static type of `List<DessertItem>` for order.  You can change the implementation for the `List` if you need to.